# Spark Scala DateType schema execution error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kudu

I get an execution error when I try to create a Schema for a dataframe in Spark Scala that says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No support for Spark SQL type DateType
    at org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.SparkUtil$.sparkTypeToKuduType(SparkUtil.scala:81)
    at org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.SparkUtil$.org$apache$kudu$spark$kudu$SparkUtil$$createColumnSchema(SparkUtil.scala:134)
    at org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.SparkUtil$$anonfun$kuduSchema$3.apply(SparkUtil.scala:120)
    at org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.SparkUtil$$anonfun$kuduSchema$3.apply(SparkUtil.scala:119)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.SparkUtil$.kuduSchema(SparkUtil.scala:119)
    at org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.KuduContext.createSchema(KuduContext.scala:234)
    at org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.KuduContext.createTable(KuduContext.scala:210)
```

where the code is like:

```
val invoicesSchema = StructType(
    List(
        StructField("id", StringType, false),
        StructField("invoicenumber", StringType, false),
        StructField("invoicedate", DateType, true)
    ))

kuduContext.createTable("invoices", invoicesSchema, Seq("id","invoicenumber"), new CreateTableOptions().setNumReplicas(3).addHashPartitions(List("id").asJava, 6))
```

How can I use the DateType for this matter? StringType and FloatType don't have this same issue in the same code

Comment: You can use String type and then cast it date type as an alternative solution.. String & Float has some kind of fixed data where as  for date type we don't have specific date format.

Comment: @Srinivas  I think we all know that, but is there not a more elegant approach?

Comment: You mean something like: StructField("invoicedate", to_date (StringType, ,"MM-dd-yyyy").as("to_date")
  ), true)?? The problem is at defining the scheme , getting the date source can be string and then converted but how to tackle the schema Datetype problem? , I need to store Date type instead of String type...

Answer (score 0):

A work-around as I call it, with an example that you need to tailor, but gives you the gist of what you need to know I think:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DateType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq( ("2018-01-01", "2018-01-31", 80)
            , ("2018-01-07","2018-01-10", 10)
            , ("2018-01-07","2018-01-31", 10)
            , ("2018-01-11","2018-01-31", 5)
            , ("2018-01-25","2018-01-27", 5)
            , ("2018-02-02","2018-02-23", 100)
            ).toDF("sd","ed","coins")

val schema = List(("sd", "date"), ("ed", "date"), ("coins", "integer"))
val newColumns = schema.map(c => col(c._1).cast(c._2))
val newDF = df.select(newColumns:_*)
newDF.show(false)
...
...
```